# Has a Tyranid Hiveship ever descended on a Tau occupied planet?

Tags: warhammer-40k

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there has ever been a large scale conflict between the Tau and the Tyranids.

And if so, is it covered in any Black Library novels or novellas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any novels encompassing that but either the latest tyranid army book or tau army book (not sure atm which one of them) has a story about the tyranids attacking a tau occupied area of space.

The tau at first had the advantage until the tyranids adapted and almost overran them....that is until the kroot arrived with their more primitive weapons and sqaushed the overadapted tyranids....who adapted again. According to the story it was a war of attrition as the tau adapted to the tyranids adapting who adapted to the adapted tau technology, .... .

Answer (score 2):

Hive Fleet Gorgon made a mess in Tau space, until it was eventually beaten by the combined efforts of the Tau and the Imperium on the planet Kel'shan.

The Tau were able to hold the fleet back quite well on Sha'draig, where their rapid adaptions to Tyranid changes forced the hive fleet to constantly breed new beasts to counter, causing it to bleed a lot of resources.

However, it is later suggested that the Tyranid were able to deal significant damage to the Tau, as Castellan Crask claimed Gorgon was only a minor Tyranid fleet and that this was proof that the Tau were weak, as they needed Imperial help to deal with them.

The reality was that the fleet had already been severely damaged by the Tau before it even got near Castellan Crask, but the Tau in return had also suffered heavy losses.